# How to print outlines and background colors from css, when using JQuery printElement, and IE8?

Tags: jquery, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

When printing my html calendar-`table` in Chrome, it works perfectly.

In IE8, on the other hand, it does not include background colors and images. I followed this [helpful post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326), in order to set it as a default wanted option.

Only problem is; it did not work. No change at all.
I know that my css is included, because it both works in Chrome, and because the table, td and tr borders, widths, heights, alignments, fonts and text colors are printed correctly. However, outlines, images and background colors are ignored. I have double checked that my printer options in IE8 settings are set to include them, and I have restarted the browser several times.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that I am required to tell IE8 that I want my colors and such in two places. Here is a link describing the second: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974128

However, it only worked on my colors. Not my outline-borders inbetween the cells...

Here is my code for starting the printElement.

```
function printCalendar(){

     $('#printable').printElement({
          overrideElementCSS:['../css/calendarprintstyle.css'],
    printBodyOptions:{ pageTitle:'calendar'}
    }); 
}
```

`#printable` is a `div`, wrapping a `table`.

Here is some sample css, that's not working properly. It is the `outline` and <strike>`background`</strike> / <strike>`background-color`</strike> that are not working.

```
table{
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-color: black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

th{

    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 1px solid black;

}

td, tr{
    height: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;

}


.calendar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;    
    float: center;
}

.calendarcell {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;    
    max-height: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
}

.datedatacell {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 20px;
    border-left: 2px;
    text-align: center;

}

.holidaystyle {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.everydaystyle {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: You need to turn on printing of backgrounds in your browser. In IE it's in the Page Setup dialog. Other browsers have this setting, too, but possible at a different place.

Comment: Yes, I just found this link myself http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974128. Unfortunately it only affected my colors. Not the outline-borders of my table cells.

Comment: IMHO you need to live with that. You always need to expect that a browser doesn't (or often can't) display something exactly as specified. IE6 can't use `display: table`, touch screen browsers can't use `:hover`, text-only browsers can't display different font sizes, voice browsers can't display colors, and some browsers can't print colored borders or backgrounds. But that is how the web works and if your design concept requires something like that, then it's time to rethink your design concept.

Comment: If you'll cook up an answer from your two comments, I'll accept it. before I changed the title of my question, It answered it perfectly, and I'll try to find a livable solution to implementing borderlines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers don't print background colors and images by default, but they usually have a setting to allow it. For the current IE the setting can be found in the Page Setup dialog.

IE doesn't seem to print colored borders either.  You always need to expect that a browser doesn't (or often can't) display something exactly as specified. IE6 can't use display: table, touch screen browsers can't use :hover, text-only browsers can't display different font sizes, voice browsers can't display colors, and some browsers can't print colored borders or backgrounds, etc. But that is how the web works and if your design concept requires something like that, then it's time to rethink your design concept.

Comment: As another update, I have realized that when printing from IE8's own printerfunction, the page, and css is printed exactly as on screen. However when I use the JQuery printElement, it as trouble with some of the CSS. I suspect it might be due to this thing I read at W3schools, about the outline-property: Note: _IE8 supports the outline property only if a !DOCTYPE is specified._ Maybe the doctype is not included when only printing a div. Or maybe printElement and IE8 does not play along...

Comment: Also: I originally didn't reallize you use `printElement`. Keep in mind that is a thrid party plugin for jQuery, it's not "offical" in anyway, so it's most likely not the same quality of jQuery itself.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I have been using W3Schools quite a bit, and often they do provide some good tips and answers, that works for my problems. It is good to know that I shouldn't necessarily consider all of it as hard facts, though. 

`printElement` is in the title btw, but I know how it is ;)

Comment: I _finally_ made it work like I wanted to. I dropped `printElement`, and made my styling sheets so that my `@media print` just hides all of my undesired elements. That way the browser takes care of printing things, the same way as it is programmed to display it. I feel good!

Comment: is it possible to tell browser to turn on printbackground color and images through jquery or css?

Answer (score 0):

you have two tasks needed to be done:

first:please note that the IE8 is not recognizing HTML5 tags and HTML5shiv (if you are included it) not working while you're printing please try to include [this file](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js) (HTML5shiv print)also in your document

you can also get html5shiv and html5print from [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) website

the specific CSS is just for fixing the style differences that might be exist when you are dealing with cross browser compatibility,that usually are in positioning styles not colors and so on,

but please note that your major problem here is that HTML5 that is not supported in IE8 and in order to fix this issue people using

https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

or  Modernizer or HTML5Shiv,when they dealing with IE8 and lower version on a HTML5 page,
this libraries powering the old browsers to correctly rendering the HTML5 pages

second: you must add a specific style sheet for printing in IE8 (if want to override the main styles or you are facing with some problem related to css like positioning) to your page you must and this Snippet to your HTML code:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/print.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

after that you must create the print.css file and add the desired styles that you want.

this is the @media print query and it's goal is to separate the main style form the print

style in the browser,and you can have totally different looks and feel while you'r printing the page from while you're browsing it.

but please not that these libraries are not working while you are printing

if you want to make the IE8 and lower versions to recognize the HTML5 tags in print mode you must add another js libraries like

https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js

HTML5shiv.print from the [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/download/) website

Comment: I want to make it clear that I already have seperate print and display styles. And that the seperate print style sheet is passed to the printer. However if I need a seperate style sheet for IE8, I would like to know what you suggest I would do differently in that css, compared to the one I have attached above. Honestly i do not think taht which css i pass is the problem, rather that I am not able to tell the browser/printer that I want my background colors and images to be printed.

Comment: if you want to separate the print style-sheet for IE8 you must include the tag,I've been mentioned.the general print tag is working on the other browsers,but if are targeting the IE8,you must use the specific tag.

Comment: and if you are thinking it's because of the html5 tags,it's some how true,because I don't think html shiv supports html5 tags while you printing,you must use the printshive too: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you, but I'm going to try and sum this up. -You suggest that I make a specific style sheet for printing only in IE8. -To be able to do that, I need to add the if-tag you have included in your answer.

After that I am a little lost. I am impressed by your english, considering I think you are from Iran, but there is still some things I can't figure out. What is HTML5shiv? Why is this relevant to me? As far as I know, i do not have a single HTML5-tag. I had one, but replaced it to make the website itself compatible with IE8.

Comment: As a last comment, I would like to try tomake a css specific for IE8, if that helps, but until I know what I need to do differently in that specific stylesheet, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If if it's any different from the desired stylesheet you are seeing,you can override it here,for example if you see the background color is different from the other browser you can write the specific css code there,the major problems is not about the colors usually but the positioning codes,might differs from a browser to another,and please note that,you have a major problem facing and that is the HTML5 Shiv is not supporting the IE8 in print   section you have to include the HTML5Shiv.print in your document to fix it https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js

Comment: please read the answer as I have explained it more vastly,but the summary is,you are facing one major problem,making the IE8 to recognize the HTML5 tags while you are printing and the solution is https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js,and the other minor problem that might be exist do to different rendering techniques in the IE8,that can be solved by specific CSS file.